# Provide short_description for model field in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Sometimes I want to display many boolean fields in the list_display view in Django Admin. Unfortunately these fields come with a long `verbose_name` which gives very ugly and large columns.

I know that you can provide a `short_description` attribute to callables for providing column names in the list_display view in Django Admin. So I reverted to doing this:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'field1', 'field2', 'short_boolfield3', 'short_boolfield4']

    def short_boolfield3(self, obj):
        return obj.boolfield3
    short_boolfield3.short_description = 'fld3'
    short_boolfield3.boolean = True

    def short_boolfield4(self, obj):
        return obj.boolfield4
    short_boolfield4.short_description = 'fld4'
    short_boolfield4.boolean = True
```

Which works, but is definitely against DRY, especially when you have **many** boolean fields.

Is there a `short_description` equivalent for Model fields?

Comment: `verbose_name` should not be long. If you need a longer help text, you can work with `help_text` instead.

Comment: You can see `short_description` as the equivalent of `verbose_name`, hence you should use it the same way. `help_text` should be used for longer descriptions.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Unfortunately `verbose_name` is the text that appears on forms, so a short 3 letter acronym is ok for admin purposes, but not for general usage. The only moment I want a short version is for admin purposes, so to fit many boolean fields together in a line for quick inspection.